# Use both sample_weight and class_weight simultaneously

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My dataset already has weighted examples. And in this binary classification I also have far more of the first class compared to the second.

Can I use both `sample_weight` and further re-weight it with `class_weight` in the `model.fit()` function?

Or do I first make a new array of new_weights and pass it to the fit function as `sample_weight`?

Edit:

TO further clarify, I already have individual weights for each sample in my dataset, and to further add to the complexity, the total sum of sample weights of the first class is far more than the total sample weights of the second class.

For example I currently have:

> y = [0,0,0,0,1,1]
>
> sample_weights = [0.01,0.03,0.05,0.02, 0.01,0.02]

so the *sum of weights* for *class '0'* is **0.11** and for *class '1'* is  **0.03**. So I should have:

> class_weight = {0 : 1. , 1: 0.11/0.03}

I need to use both `sample_weight` AND `class_weight` features. If one overrides the other then I will have to create new sample_weights and then use `fit()` or `train_on_batch()`.

So my question is, can I use both, or does one override the other?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can surely do both if you want, the thing is if that is what you *need*. According to the keras [docs](https://keras.io/models/model/):

> - **class_weight:** Optional dictionary mapping class indices (integers) to a weight (float) value, used for weighting the loss function (during training only). This can be useful to **tell the model to "pay more attention" to samples from an under-represented class**.
> - **sample_weight:** Optional Numpy array of weights for the training samples, used for weighting the loss function (during training only). You can either pass a flat (1D) Numpy array **with the same length as the input samples (1:1 mapping between weights and samples)**, or in the case of temporal data [...].

So given that you mention that you *"have far more of the first class compared to the second"* I think that you should go for the `class_weight` parameter. There you can indicate that ratio your dataset presents so you can compensate for imbalanced data classes. The `sample_weight` is more when you want to define a weight or importance for *each* data element.

For example if you pass:

```
class_weight = {0 : 1. , 1: 50.}
```

you will be saying that every sample from class `1` would count as 50 samples from class `0`, therefore giving more "importance" to your elements from class `1` (as you have less of those samples surely). You can custom this to fit your own needs. More info con imbalanced datasets on [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/how-to-set-class-weights-for-imbalanced-classes-in-keras) great question.

**Note:** To further compare both parameters, have in mind that passing `class_weight` as `{0:1., 1:50.}` would be equivalent to pass `sample_weight` as `[1.,1.,1.,...,50.,50.,...]`, given you had samples whose classes where `[0,0,0,...,1,1,...]`.

As we can see it is more practical to use `class_weight` on this case, and `sample_weight` could be of use on more specific cases where you actually want to give an "importance" to each sample individually. Using both can also be done if the case requires it, but one has to have in mind its cumulative effect.

**Edit:** As per your new question, digging on the Keras [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py#L499) it seems that indeed **`sample_weights` overrides `class_weights`**, here is the piece of code that does it on the `_standarize_weigths` method (line 499):

```
if sample_weight is not None:
    #...Does some error handling...
    return sample_weight #simply returns the weights you passed

elif isinstance(class_weight, dict):
    #...Some error handling and computations...
    #Then creates an array repeating class weight to match your target classes
    weights = np.asarray([class_weight[cls] for cls in y_classes
                          if cls in class_weight])

    #...more error handling...
    return weights
```

This means that you can only use one or the other, but not both. Therefore you will indeed need to multiply your `sample_weights` by the ratio you need to compensate for the imbalance.

---

**Update:** As of the moment of this edit (March 27, 2020), looking at the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training_utils.py#L423) of `training_utils.standardize_weights()` we can see that it now supports *both* `class_weights` and `sample_weights`:

> Everything gets normalized to a single sample-wise (or timestep-wise)
>       weight array. **If both `sample_weights` and `class_weights` are provided,
>       the weights are multiplied together.**

Comment: Actually, `sample_weight` will override `class_weight` in Keras, and the latter will have no effect at all (somewhat unexpected IMO). So the OP may need to merge the weights into one before passing it to `fit`.

Comment: @Yu-Yang interesting, thanks for sharing (will try that and update when on desktop). Still how OP describes it seems that using `class_weight` will suffice for balancing imbalanced datasets. If further customization is needed then manual merging and calculating `sample_weighs` could help more.

Comment: Hi, indeed I want to use both, so if one overrides the other then I need to first multiply the two.
I clarified the problem in the edit to the original question.

Comment: @user7867665 digging Keras source code I found an answer to your new question, updating shortly.

Comment: @DarkCygnus Thanks! That clears it up. I'm do the re-weighting before training with `sample_weights`. Perhaps we make a feature request

Comment: @user7867665 surely that is a feature that may be useful. Go ahead :)

Comment: @DarkCygnus : Cheers for your explanation on sample_weights. Is it just training_sample * weight ? I don't think so. For exemple I've read model.fit(s_batch, prob_batch, sample_weight=r_batch, verbose=0) but s_batch shape = (200, 4) and r_batch.shape = (200,). Now I'm confused, if you see this post and if you want to clarify this, I'll be thankfull :).

Comment: Hey @CechMS glad I could help. To sum it up, as we can se by the update to my answer now keras supports both options. So you could give more/less weight to certain class and also give more/less weight to single samples if you want to... I didn't quite get what you are confused about. Are you asking what giving more weight means in terms of training? Please clarify and I will gladly comment :)

Comment: If you are asking what does giving more weight to a class mean in terms of training or batch training, you could think of it like this: if you give 2x weight to class A with respect to class B, it's equivalent to making one copy of each sample of class A, and then proceed with batch training. That way, elements form class A will be "seen" twice. Same if giving weight to a specific sample, say sample S_i. If you give 2x weight to it it's the same as training over it twice. Does this make it clearer?

Answer (score 1):

To add a little to DarkCygnus answer, for those who actually need to use class weight & sample weights simultaneously:
Here is a code, that I use for generating sample weights for classifying multiclass temporal data in sequences:
(targets is an array of dimension [#temporal, #categories] with values being in set(#classes), class_weights is an array of [#categories, #classes]).
The generated sequence has the same length as the targets array and the common usecase in batching is to pad the targets with zeros *and the sample weights also up to the same size*, thus making the network ignore the padded data.

```
def multiclass_temoral_class_weights(targets, class_weights):
    s_weights = np.ones((targets.shape[0],))
    # if we are counting the classes, the weights do not exist yet!
    if class_weights is not None:
        for i in range(len(s_weights)):
            weight = 0.0
            for itarget, target in enumerate(targets[i]):
                weight += class_weights[itarget][int(round(target))]
            s_weights[i] = weight
    return s_weights
```

Comment: Good addition. Seems that Keras now supports the use of both weights simultaneously (updated my answer)